# How can I Insert data into a shadow dom using React?

Tags: reactjs, shadow-dom

I am trying to insert data into a shadow dom using React.

The code below used to work, but when a made "unrelated" changes to other code it stopped working. I think that the problem is that the component now (as compared to before) only runs once. On this run shadowHost is null so shadowRoot is not attached.

What is a reasonable way to make this work?

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export enum ViewerStyle {
  Svg = "svg",
  ProcessedSvg = "processedsvg",
}

type Props = {
  serialized: string;
  viewerStyleModifier: ViewerStyle;
};

export default function SvgImageViewer(props: Props) {
  const { serialized, viewerStyleModifier: xmlType } = props;

  if (!serialized) {
    return <div className={`viewer viewer--${xmlType}`}></div>;
  }

  const shadowHost = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  let shadowRoot: ShadowRoot | null = null;
  if (shadowHost.current instanceof HTMLElement && !shadowHost.current.shadowRoot) {
    shadowRoot = shadowHost.current.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
  }

  if (shadowRoot instanceof ShadowRoot) {
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <div class="viewer viewer--${xmlType}">
        ${serialized}
      </div>
    `;
  }

  return <div ref={shadowHost}></div>;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an effect (which runs when component got mounted) to insert data into the shadow root. The effect should rely on `serialized` to run (which means whenever `serialized` changes its value, the effect runs and replace the shadow root with new `serialized` value)

```
  export default function SvgImageViewer(props: Props) {
  const { serialized, viewerStyleModifier: xmlType } = props;
  const shadowHost = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
     if (serialized) {
        const shadowRoot = shadowHost.current.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
        shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
          <div class="viewer viewer--${xmlType}">
            ${serialized}
          </div>`;
     }

  }, [serialized])
  
  if (!serialized) {
    return <div className={`viewer viewer--${xmlType}`}></div>;
  }

  return <div ref={shadowHost}></div>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! What is the advantage of using an effect compared to the previous solution? Both require the ref to be set before the component is rendered with serialized data.

Comment: Using the effect to make sure that effect runs when your component got mounted into the DOM (at which time the ref has its value, since ref is the reference to DOM node). In your first solution, on the first render, although there's no serialized data, the `div` still renders so the ref has its value. On subsequence renders, thanks to the [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html), the ref value stays the same, so that's why your ref is accessible and works as expected on subsequence renders. If this resolved your question, a vote up or answer marked would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is to change

```
  if (!serialized) {
    return <div className={`viewer viewer--${xmlType}`}></div>;
  }
```

to

```
  if (!serialized) {
    return <div ref={shadowHost} className={`viewer viewer--${xmlType}`}></div>;
  }
```

> If you pass a ref object to React with `<div ref={myRef} />`, React will set its .current property to the corresponding DOM node whenever that node changes. (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

This however, still relies on the component rendering at least once before serialized is et.